# Prove that $ \int_0^1 x(\sec x)^2 \,dx < 1.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, approximate-integration

Prove that $ \int_0^1 x(\sec x)^2 \,dx < 1.$

I tried a few combinations but nothing seems to work, as the integral is quite close to 1 itself. And question strictly inhibits use of calculators to calculate ln(cos1) or tan1

The integral is tan1+ lncos1 but there is no way in my mind to get ahead with just this, so any ideas or hints will be a lot appreciated.

Comment: The numerical value is $0.941781$, so what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the question “strictly inhibits use of calculators to calculate $\ln (\cos 1)$ or $\tan (1)$”. So, it’s a matter of estimating these quantities with sufficiently strong upper bounds.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The problem is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: Considering the Taylor series of $x \sec^2 (x)$ at $x=0$ and integrating term-by-term, empirically, it seems to be the case that each summand is bounded above by $2^{-n}$ (from $x^7$ onwards anyway). This may be able to get you most of the way there -- if you can find a proof.

Comment: Oh... "inhibit" actually means *prohibit*.  Got it.

Comment: @legionwhale i quite didn't understand your solution

Comment: @DavidG.Stork inhibit was written at the question's original place, haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the problem statement,
$$\int_0^1 x \sec^2 x \,dx = \tan 1 + \log \cos 1.$$

Expanding in a power series about $x = 0$ gives that
$$\log \cos x \leq -\frac12 x^2 - \frac1{12} x^4 ,$$
so $$\log \cos 1 \leq - \frac7{12} .$$

To bound $\tan 1$ from above, we exploit the fact that $1 \approx \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Rearranging the tangent difference identity gives
$$\tan 1 = \frac{\tan \frac\pi3 - \tan \left(\frac\pi 3 - 1\right)}{\tan \frac\pi3 \tan \left(\frac\pi 3 - 1\right)+ 1} = \frac{\sqrt 3 - \tan \left(\frac\pi 3 - 1\right)}{\sqrt 3 \tan \left(\frac\pi 3 - 1\right)+ 1} .$$
Since $3 + \frac18 < \pi$, we have $\frac1{24} < \frac\pi3 - 1$, and since $\tan x > x$ on $\left(0, \frac\pi2\right)$,
$$\tan 1 < \frac{\sqrt 3 - \frac1{24}}{\sqrt 3 \cdot \frac1{24} + 1} = \frac{577 \sqrt 3 - 96}{573}.$$ We've now shown that
$$\tan 1 + \log \cos 1 < -\frac7{12} + \frac{577 \sqrt 3 - 96}{573} ,$$
and it's routine arithmetic to verify that the right-hand side is smaller than $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats a great way!